# I have an equation involving the $W(x)$ function.

Tags: real-analysis, lambert-w

This is the equation:

$e^{-x}=W\left(\left(xe^{x}\right)^{-1}\right)$

I was trying to find similarities between $\exp(x)$  and $\ln(x)$.
Then I starting working on this equation:

$-\exp(-x)=\ln(x)$

By algebra I came across that big fat equation on the extreme top.

You can see these 2 equations are the same, I tried Wolfram Alpha and got this value:

$x ≈ 0.56714329...$.

But anyway it would be helpful if anybody can help me give a intuitive way to derive the value for $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

> \begin{align}\e^{-x}&=\W\left(\left(x\e^{x}\right)^{-1}\right)\tag{1}\label{1}\end{align}

\begin{align}
\e^{-x}\exp(\e^{-x})
&=
\W\left(\left(x\e^{x}\right)^{-1}\right)
\exp\left(\W\left(\left(x\e^{x}\right)^{-1}\right)\right)
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\e^{-x}\exp(\e^{-x})
&=
\left(x\e^{x}\right)^{-1}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\exp(\e^{-x})
&=
x^{-1}
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\e^{-x}
&=
-\ln x
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
-x\e^{-x}
&=
x\ln x
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Both sides of \eqref{6} are in the form $u\exp u$, so we can apply $\W$ function to simplify it:
\begin{align}
\W(-x\e^{-x})
&=
\W(x\ln x)
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
-x
&=
\ln x
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}
And \eqref{8} can be easily rearranged to $u\exp u$ form as well:

\begin{align}
\exp(-x)
&=
x
\tag{9}\label{9}
,\\
x\exp(x)&=1
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{align}

hence we can apply $\W$ again to get the answer:

\begin{align}
\W\left(x\exp(x)\right)&=\W(1)
\tag{11}\label{11}
,\\
x&=\W(1)=\Omega
\tag{12}\label{12}
.
\end{align}

For the $\Omega$ constant see [A030178](http://oeis.org/A030178).

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 1):

There are a few main ways to find the answer. The first way is without using the W-Lambert function nesting functions proven [in this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q8rywhevz4). Assume that x=k in the left hand side:

$$\mathrm{-e^{-x}=ln(x)\implies x=-ln(-ln(…-ln(k)…))=e^{-e^{…^{-k}}}= 0.5671432904097838729999686622103555497538157871865125081351310792230457930866}$$

**One can essentially “undo” recursion to find a formula:**

For the logarithm answer:

$$\mathrm{-e^{-x}=ln(x)\implies e^{-x}=-ln(x)\implies -x=ln(-ln(x))\implies x=-ln(-ln(x))}$$
This just isolated x in the left hand side. If we take x=-ln(x) then we can plug in -ln(x) for x or just x=-ln(-ln(x)). Since we can do this, we can **undo** the recursion to get x=-ln(x) and solve as seen above from there:

$$\mathrm{x=-ln(-ln(x))\implies x=-ln(x)\implies e^x=\frac{1}{x}\implies xe^x=1\implies x=W(1)=Ω}$$

From the recursive exponential answer:
$$\mathrm{x=e^{-e^{-x}}\implies e^{-x}=x\implies 1=xe^x\implies x=W(1)=Ω}$$

The answer is that $x=\Omega=W(1)$. This is called the [Omega constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OmegaConstant.html). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: I didn't understand that $x=-\ln(-\ln(x)) \overset{?}{\implies} x=-\ln(x)$.Please explain this part....

Comment: @ShivanshMisra:
$$\mathrm{-e^{-x}=ln(x)\implies e^{-x}=-ln(x)\implies -x=ln(-ln(x))\implies x=-ln(-ln(x))}$$ 
This just isolated x in the left hand side. If we take x=-ln(x) then we can plug in -ln(x) for x or just x=-ln(-ln(x)). Since we can do this, we can **undo** the recursion to get x=-ln(x) and solve as seen above from there. Does this help?